# How do i keep the footer always at the bottom while content resize with different resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I made a site for a friend of mine. You can see it [here](http://ggson-gaming.de/corium/).

The thing is i want the bottom part of the page actually be on the bottom of the site. And the images resizing with another resolution.

Example:

Watching the site on a 1366x768 resolution the page is always in view like [here](http://i.gyazo.com/0d9fd2f093af3ace731b08d8a65389bc.png):

But when i switch on a higher resolution with a bigger height(1280x1024) it looks like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/43df1eb2020d7d7c12b08e6d9a2482f2.png)

As you can see there is many space between the bottom of the page and the bottom of the site itself. 
I want it to keep it like the 1366x768 resolution always "fullsite" the images getting bigger at a higher height and the "footer" is always at the bottom of the page. Like a dynamic fullscreen page.

I hope you can help me i thought about media queries but i am not sure if this is the best solution and if so how it would be the best to actually query them.

Thanks for your time i appreciate your help !

Comment: Thanks will take a look at this Steve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good practice to fix the footer to the bottom, because it would hide content and worst case would be no space for any content if the window height is smaller than nav height + footer height.

In this case if you really want to move the footer to bottom, I'd rather use some javascript to add padding-bottom to the content (slider in this case), if the window height is bigger than your website height:

```
var windowHeight  = window.innerHeight;
var websiteHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).height);

if (windowHeight > websiteHeight) {
    var diff = windowHeight - websiteHeight;
    document.getElementById('slider').style.paddingBottom = diff+'px';
}
```

Put this inside a function and call it in body onload. Notice that if you hover over the shoe, the content height will increase and move the footer down further. Thats why in responsive design you usually don't fix things vertically, but instead let the content height be a flexible variable...

Another approach would be CSS min-height property on the content to make it take up a minimum amount of the browser height.